# python xlsxwriter conditional format does not update

Tags: python, excel, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to apply a conditional format to an excel file and faced some strange behavior.

The code looks as follows:

```
# fill table with data
format1 = workbook.add_format()
format1.set_bg_color('red')
conditionalFormatOptions = {'type' : 'formula',
                            'criteria' : '=ODER($C2="<unknown>",$C2="unknown")',
                            'format' : format1 }
worksheet.conditional_format(1, 0, len(selectedFiles), len(tableContent)-1, conditionalFormatOptions)
workbook.close()
```

The strange thing is, it *kind of* works :-) If I open the conditional formatting options in excel, edit the rule by double-clicking it and hit ok without changing anything, the rule applies correctly. It looks like there is a refresh or something similar missing. Any ideas how to solve this? I am working with python 2.7.12 excel 2013 and the latest version of xlsxwrite (0.9.4)

Comment: I'm using the german version of excel, hence the "ODER", which is OR...

Comment: You need to use the US English version of the formula. See the XlsxWriter docs: [Non US Excel functions and syntax](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#non-us-excel-functions-and-syntax)

Comment: Thanks. Stupid me. I've changed the semicolon to a comma but missed the obvious function name... Even mentioned it in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by jmcnamara, all formulas need to be in US-English notation. Changing "ODER" to "OR" solves the problem. Thanks a lot!